# Growing circle figure

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to draw figures related to a computation algorithm which involves circles growing and adjusting themselves in every figure. Later I need to use ellipses instead of circles. Is there any generic approach to drawing this (someway I can just substitute the draw circle command with a draw ellipse command). Figures are as below
[image: swell cirlces]

and for ellipses
[image: swell ellipse]

The MWE for the first steps of the packing are as below,(I used a plot digitzser to find the coordinates

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[black,dashed](1,1) rectangle (11,11);
\draw[black,thick] (1.2040104901,1.1317523057) circle (0.1cm);
\draw[black,thick] (5.8994695942,1.3162055336) circle (0.1cm);
\draw[black,thick] (10.5669335679,1.2898550725) circle (0.1cm);
\draw[black,thick] (4.1983631966,3.4110671937) circle (0.1cm);
\draw[black,thick] (8.2803428063,2.884057971) circle (0.1cm);
\draw[black,thick] (5.9119655049,4.3860342556) circle (0.1cm);
\draw[black,thick] (1.2345798853,5.3083003953) circle (0.1cm);
\draw[black,thick] (10.5727256638,6.046113307) circle (0.1cm);
\draw[black,thick] (1.5432771464,7.8115942029) circle (0.1cm);
\draw[black,thick] (5.8987187669,7.7984189723) circle (0.1cm);
\draw[black,thick] (10.7607006291,8.8919631094) circle (0.1cm);
\draw[black,thick] (1.2298067692,10.8023715415) circle (0.1cm);
\draw[black,thick] (4.460080124,11.0395256917) circle (0.1cm);
\draw[black,thick] (10.7549621637,10.8155467721) circle (0.1cm);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Let me get back to you on that...its not going minimal but I will give it a try :)

Comment: Are the centers moving?(it looks like this) How do they move?

Comment: Define an x radius and y radius for both, just set them equal for circles.

Comment: One other thing that I can think of is to find the final coordinates and radii of circles in fig (f) and work backwards, but I don't think that going to work for the ellipse case

Comment: If you say `circle (1mm and 2mm)` you'll get an ellipse, rather than a circle. But I'm not sure how helpful that is.

Comment: I worked around a bit and I think TeX/TikZ wouldn't be the best option for this, especially when I need exact coordinates to indicate circles are perfectly touching each other. I will have to resort to the packing code itself(matlab) and freeze the process at different steps to get the pictures. Thanks for the all the comments though